# Picture in Picture Opens new window of the app and shows tons of recent tasks

Tags: android, android-layout, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I am playing my videos in PIP mode when on Pressback button.
Everything is fine. video playing perfectly. navigation etc.
But problem is when i Close PIP mode.
There is new window created on my recent apps window.
IMAGE.
[See those white windows those are left by pip mode when i click pip mode close button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLWzw.jpg)

Is there any way to solve this and close activity when I close the pip mode please help..

Comment: looks like whenever you closing the PIP mode, a new instance of the activity is created. You can modify the launch mode to fix this problem. refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManifestForTasks and https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents#attr-doclaunch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use below `configuration` in `Manifest` for your `Activity` to avoid multiple instances

```
<activity
      android:name=".view.activities.PlayerActivity"
      android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation|uiMode"
      android:excludeFromRecents="true"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:resizeableActivity="false"
      android:taskAffinity=".PlayerActivity"
      android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      tools:targetApi="n"/>
```

And below approach to `finish` the `activity` when closed in PIP mode

```
var isInPipMode: Boolean = false

override fun onPictureInPictureModeChanged(
        isInPictureInPictureMode: Boolean,
        newConfig: Configuration?
    ) {
        super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig)
        isInPipMode = isInPictureInPictureMode
    }

 override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if(isInPipMode){
            finish()
        }
    }
```